# how to trigger automation test when a release given to dev code base

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

I'm setting up CI\CD integration in azure devops. I have done the configurations and now looking a way to trigger the automation tests when a release is given in dev code base.(Automation code base and dev code base in separate repository) How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to use the following extension.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options:

1. Trigger automation code test build after the code build ([there is an options to trigger the build after another build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#build-completion-triggers))
2. Use some sort of script to talk to Azure Devops Api and trigger needed build as the last step of the regular build (which seems a bit hacky).

Comment: There is only option to trigger build after another build in the same repository. I could not find the option to trigger the automation code build after dev code release

Comment: you can trigger any build after any build

Comment: Thats in same repository right? not if the source codes are in different projects

Comment: no, it doesnt matter at all, any build after any build. they have to be in the same azure devops project, but it can host multiple repos. so that is fine